# make div appear over another div on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, scroll

Firstly I'm sorry, there's probably quite an easy way to do this but I'm an amateur with javascript, etc. which I expect you need.  Here's what i want to do:

I have a basic 'parallax' website (something along the lines of [this](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/demos/parallax/)) but I'd like to add a footer which covers half of the bottom slide when you scroll down to it, with the content in the bottom slide staying put.

As in at the moment, the content in the fifth slide moves when you scroll down to the footer, but I want it to stop at the fifth slide, with the footer sliding over the top.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Sorry: here's the Lorem ipsumed code:

```js
//I have no idea what javascript i should be using.
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 15px;
}
.page {
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}
.page-title {
  font-family: 'Quattrocento Sans';
  font-size: 2.5em;
  transform: translateY(100%);
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}
.page-sub {
  font-family: 'Coming Soon';
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 50px;
}
.page-para {
  font-family: 'Quattrocento Sans';
  font-size: 1.2em;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-left: 50%;
  position: relative;
}
.page-link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #F0C808;
}
.page-link:hover {
  color: #F0C808;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.link-box {
  color: #F0C808;
  background-color: #07A0C3;
  border: 1px solid #07A0C3;
  font-family: 'Coming Soon';
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
  height: 3em;
  width: 8em;
  line-height: 3em;
  bottom: 100px;
  right: 150px;
  position: absolute;
}

#page-one {
  background: url('img/page-one.jpg') no-repeat fixed;
  background-size: 100%;
}
.main-title {
  font-family: 'Quattrocento Sans';
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
  padding: auto;
  align-items: center;
  width: 35%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}
#page-two {
  background: url(img/page-two.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-color: #E2E2E2;
}
#page-three {
  background: url(img/page-three.jpg) no-repeat fixed;
  background-size: 100%;
}
#page-four {
  background: url(img/page-four.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-color: #E2E2E2;
}
#page-five {
  background: url(img/page-five.jpg) no-repeat fixed;
  background-size: 100%;
}
.page-five-para {
  margin: 0;
}
.page-five-bold {
  font-family: 'Coming Soon';
  font-size: 1.2em;
  margin: 0;
}
#footer {
  background-color: #E2E2E2;
}
.foot {
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 33%;
  height: 50vh;
}
h5 {
  font-family: 'Coming Soon';
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
.right-foot-spacer {
  height: 2.41em;
  margin: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
.foot-content {
  font-family: 'Quattrocento Sans';
  font-size: 1.2em;
  margin: 20px;
}
.foot-list {
  list-style: none;
}
.foot-link {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
blockquote {
  margin: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.right-footer p {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quattrocento+Sans|Coming+Soon' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="page" id="page-one">
    <h1 class="main-title">Title</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="page" id="page-two">
    <h2 class="page-title">Page two title</h2>
    <h4 class="page-sub">subtitle</h4>
    <p class="page-para">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer auctor mi sit amet porta gravida. Phasellus bibendum leo ut tortor semper, vitae euismod arcu mattis. Proin sagittis risus sollicitudin eros finibus, et semper ex varius. In nec sagittis
      metus. Aliquam in sem eu diam pretium vulputate. Sed pretium ante id sem posuere mollis. Suspendisse sed massa purus. Donec et nulla rhoncus, gravida lectus ac, pretium quam.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="page" id="page-three">
    <h2 class="page-title">Page three title</h2>
    <h4 class="page-sub">subtitle</h4>
    <p class="page-para">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer auctor mi sit amet porta gravida. Phasellus bibendum leo ut tortor semper, vitae euismod arcu mattis. Proin sagittis risus sollicitudin eros finibus, et semper ex varius. In nec sagittis
      metus. Aliquam in sem eu diam pretium vulputate. Sed pretium ante id sem posuere mollis. Suspendisse sed massa purus. Donec et nulla rhoncus, gravida lectus ac, pretium quam.</p>
    <a href="http://www.google.com" class="page-link">
      <div class="link-box">Link</div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="page" id="page-four">
    <h2 class="page-title">Page title</h2>
    <h4 class="page-sub">subtitle</h4>
    <p class="page-para">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer auctor mi sit amet porta gravida. Phasellus bibendum leo ut tortor semper, vitae euismod arcu mattis. Proin sagittis risus sollicitudin eros finibus, et semper ex varius. In nec sagittis
      metus. Aliquam in sem eu diam pretium vulputate. Sed pretium ante id sem posuere mollis. Suspendisse sed massa purus. Donec et nulla rhoncus, gravida lectus ac, pretium quam.</p>
    <a href="http://www.bing.com" class="page-link">
      <div class="link-box">Link</div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="page page-five" id="page-five">
    <h2 class="page-title">Page title</h2>
    <h4 class="page-sub">Lorem ipsum dolor</h4>
    <div class="page-para">
      <p class="page-five-para">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer auctor mi sit amet porta gravida.</p>
      <h6 class="page-five-bold">Lorem ipsum dolor</h6>
      <p class="page-five-para">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="footer">
    <div class="foot left-footer">
      <h5>Lorem Ipsum</h5>
      <p class="foot-content email">someone@example.com</p>
    </div>

    <div class="foot center-footer">
      <h5>Footer</h5>
      <ul class="foot-content">
        <li class="foot-list"><a href="http://www.google.com" class="foot-link">Google</a>
        </li>
        <li class="foot-list"><a href="http://www.bing.com" class="foot-link">Bing</a>
        </li>
        <li class="foot-list"><a href="http://www.yahoo.com" class="foot-link">Yahoo</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="foot right-footer">
      <div class="right-foot-spacer"></div>
      <div class="foot-content quote">
        <blockquote>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</blockquote>
        <p>-Lorem Ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?  If so, what does your code look like?

Comment: Try to be more specific. This is very general question. Show us what you have tried (i.e. code, code and code). The problem with generic question is there are many ways to solve the same problem- and there will be useless discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood your question correctly, one way to achieve the effect you are looking for is by monitoring the `getBoundingClientRect().top` property of the final `<div>` and the `getBoundingClientRect().bottom` property of the penultimate `<div>`.

- When the `getBoundingClientRect().top` property of the final `<div>` hits the top of the viewport, you can change the element's style rules to fix it in that position;
- When the `getBoundingClientRect().bottom` property of the penultimate `<div>` comes back into view at the top of the viewport, you can unfix the final `<div>` so that it starts scrolling as normal again.

**Example:**

```js
function fixPage5() {
 var footer = document.getElementsByTagName('footer')[0];
    var pages = document.getElementsByClassName('page');

    if (pages[(pages.length - 1)].getBoundingClientRect().top < 1) {
        pages[(pages.length - 1)].classList.add('fixed');
        footer.style.marginTop = '424px';
    }

    if (pages[(pages.length - 2)].getBoundingClientRect().bottom > -1) {
        footer.style.marginTop = '0';
        pages[(pages.length - 1)].classList.remove('fixed');
    }
}

window.addEventListener('scroll',fixPage5,false);
```

```css
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.page {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 400px;
padding: 12px;
font-size: 72px;
}

footer {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
z-index: 12;
height: 400px;
font-size: 72px;
color: rgb(255,255,255);
background-color: rgb(31,31,31);
}

.page:nth-of-type(odd) {
color: rgb(255,255,255);
background-color: rgb(127,127,127);
}

.fixed {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: -12;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">Page One</div>
<div class="page">Page Two</div>
<div class="page">Page Three</div>
<div class="page">Page Four</div>
<div class="page">Page Five</div>
<footer>Footer</footer>
```

Comment: thanks for this.  unfortunately my page five background picture shrinks.  (probably due to the `fixed` attribute)  when i try to correct this with `background-size: 100%`, there is white space below it.  Is there any way of correcting this?

Comment: Yes, there will be a way of correcting it. Once the element is `position:fixed;` it is outside the document flow so it will need explicit `height`, `margin`, `padding` etc.

Comment: yep. done it with a `width: 100%` on the `#page-five` id..  One more issue (fussy or what.. :P) - the footer appears a quarter of the way up.  is there any way of changing this?

Comment: If you have got this far, I'll bet you can fix that issue yourself within the next 2 days. And the exercise of solving it yourself will give you a greater sense of achievement and teach you more than I can.